# npm doesn't install modules under ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, npm

I installed NPM without problems but whenever I try to install a module the terminal just hangs and does nothing (at least it seems like it does nothing ...)

I waited for 5 mins but nothing changes.

[image: screenshot terminal]

**edit**

using node version 0.5.4-pre and npm 1.0.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downgraded to node 0.4.10 and now everything is working alright.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to get around this is:

1) Remove your node directory

```
$ rm -rf node
```

2) get branch 0.4

```
$ git clone -b v0.4 git://github.com/joyent/node.git
```

3) Compile and install it (sudo)

```
$ sudo su -
$ cd node
$ make clean
$ ./configure
$ make -j
$ sudo su -
# make install
```

4) Re-download & install npm, this is important!

```
# curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

5) Exit sudo, rebuild your search index and install your module

```
# exit
$ npm search
$ npm install mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was solved after reinstall nodejs and npm. Then I write [simple installation shell script](https://gist.github.com/1064016) to automatic installation with modules. And as i know it's not recomended to run node from root.